# hpple html parse iphone sdk help?

Tags: iphone, html-parsing, deprecated, hpple

I want to parse html.. so I have found some sample code over: http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/02/24/parsing-html-iphone-development/
it uses hpple to parse html... but there is one problem this application is constantly crashing for some reason most probably it is this line over here:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.objectgraph.com/contact.html"];
NSString *contents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSData *htmlData = [contents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

xCode gives me warning stringWithCOntentsofVariable is deprecated..

so could anyone help me solve this problem....by showing what code should I change?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

30 seconds in [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBEGJCC) shows:

> Returns a string created by reading data from the file named by a given URL. (Deprecated in Mac OS X v10.4. Use `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` or `stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` instead.)

So, it looks like you should be using `stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error` or `stringWithContentsOfURL:usedEncoding:error:` instead.

Just like the documentation says.